# c++ new class array with parameter

Tags: c++, class, new-operator

Refering to https://github.com/cameron314/readerwriterqueue , there is a sample code like following :

```
ReaderWriterQueue<int> q(100);       // Reserve space for at least 100 elements up front

q.enqueue(17);                       // Will allocate memory if the queue is full
bool succeeded = q.try_enqueue(18);  // Will only succeed if the queue has an empty slot (never allocates)
assert(succeeded);

int number;
succeeded = q.try_dequeue(number);  // Returns false if the queue was empty

assert(succeeded && number == 17);

// You can also peek at the front item of the queue (consumer only)
int* front = q.peek();
assert(*front == 18);
succeeded = q.try_dequeue(number);
assert(succeeded && number == 18);
front = q.peek();
assert(front == nullptr);           // Returns nullptr if the queue was empty
```

Suppose I like to have a array for ReaderWriterQueue constructed with parameter 100 , how can I define the var ?!

```
ReaderWriterQueue<int> qp[1024] ;
```

that is ok , but I like all 1024 of them with parameter 100 ,

```
ReaderWriterQueue<int>(100) qp[1024] ;
```

won't compiled  , I try to use pointer  :

```
ReaderWriterQueue<int>* qptr;
qptr = new ReaderWriterQueue<int>(1024) ;
```

will work , but without parameter 100 ,

```
qptr = new ReaderWriterQueue<int>(100) (1024) ;
```

won't compile , so how can I make an array of 1024's ReaderWriterQueue , all of them constructed with parameter 100 ?!

Comment: Can you use boost?

Comment: I prefer not to use boost , thanks for information .

Comment: That's a shame `boost::optional` used with `boost::in_place` would do it.

Comment: You could declare a char array large enough to hold the queues and then inplace construct them into the array.

Answer (score 1):

As `ReaderWriterQueue` is neither copy-able/movable, you may use `static_vector` from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage

```
template<class T, std::size_t N>
class static_vector
{
    // properly aligned uninitialized storage for N T's
    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type data[N];
    std::size_t m_size = 0;

public:
    // Create an object in aligned storage
    template<typename ...Args> void emplace_back(Args&&... args) 
    {
        if( m_size >= N ) // possible error handling
            throw std::bad_alloc{};
        new (data + m_size) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        ++m_size;
    }

    // Access an object in aligned storage
    const T& operator[](std::size_t pos) const 
    {
        return *reinterpret_cast<const T*>(data + pos);
    }

    // Delete objects from aligned storage
    ~static_vector() 
    {
        for (std::size_t pos = 0; pos < m_size; ++pos) {
            reinterpret_cast<const T*>(data+pos)->~T();
        }
    }
};
```

And then use it

```
static_vector<ReaderWriterQueue<int>, 1024> queues;

for (int i = 0; i != 1024; ++i) {
    queues.emplace_back(100)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with `vector` is trivial:

```
std::vector<ReaderWriterQueue<int>> qp(1024, ReaderWriterQueue<int>(100));
```

This of course assumes that `ReaderWriterQueue` has a (public) copy constructor which does the right thing. However, this is not the case in the current version of the `ReaderWriterQueue`, so what you're trying to do is not possible.

Comment: thanks , but copy constructor is in private area , so it won't help

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use arrays, you can use `std::fill` to fill its elements as follows:

```
ReaderWriterQueue<int> qp[1024];
std::fill(begin(qp), end(qp), ReaderWriterQueue<int>(100));
```

As it's pointed out in the comments, this would work if `ReaderWriterQueue` is copyable, which seems that it is not. Then, another solution would be to declare array or vector of (smart) pointers to `ReaderWriterQueue` as follows, and initialize it later:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ReaderWriterQueue<int>>> qp(1024);
for(auto& x : qp)
    x = make_shared<ReaderWriterQueue<int>>(100);
```

Comment: `ReaderWriterQueue` has no default or copy constructor so this doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks , compile error , copy and assignment constructor is in private area .

Comment: Your vector of shared_ptr's has every element in the vector pointing at the same Queue, which is not what's wanted.